# How can you prefix a Python pathlib.Path with another path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have a `pathlib.Path('/etc')`.
If I need to prefix it with `pathlib.Path('/mnt/chroot')` and do something like:

`Path('/mnt/chroot') / Path('/etc')`

I just end up with: `PosixPath('/etc')`, presumably because both `Path`'s are absolute paths, and can't be concatenated.

I can hack together a solution with something like:

`Path('/mnt/chroot') / str(Path('/etc')).removeprefix('/')`

But that is long-winded, and hackish. Is there a simpler, proper way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn `Path('/etc')` into a relative path with the `relative_to` method:

```
Path('/mnt/chroot') / Path('/etc').relative_to('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to expand on Kyle's answer with a cross platform solution. It dynamically gets the root of the filesystem.

```
root = os.path.abspath(".").split(os.path.sep)[0] + os.path.sep
path = Path("/mnt/chroot") / Path("/etc").relative_to(root)
```

Do not know if this adds anything but here it is.

Comment: A `Path` object also has a `root` property which seems to return what you would expect.

Comment: ``root`` here seems to be a convoluted and error-prone way to get [``pathlib.Path.anchor``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.anchor). Note there is no guarantee that the root of ``.`` is the root of ``/etc``, and "splitting on ``os.path.sep``" is just ``pathlib.Path.parents``.